# How to return a string from a vbscript which is executed from a python file

Tags: python, vbscript

I am new to VBScript and am executing a vbs file from python file. Now in the vbs file there is a `String value` which I need to return back to the python file. I have tried with `WScript.Quit()/ WScript.StdOut()` . But it seems they don't support Strings. 'coz there is a Type mismatch error.

Is there any other way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your .vbs in the console, i.e. using `CScript.exe`, the you can redirect the output using ">":

```
CScript example.vbs //NoLogo > output.txt
```

And inside your .vbs use `WScript.StdOut` object with `.Write` or `.WriteLine` method. For example:

```
' example.vbs
Main

Sub Main()
    Dim result
    result = 1 / Cos(25)
    WScript.StdOut.Write result
End Sub
```

But if you run your script with `WScript.exe`...

```
WScript example2.vbs
```

...you'll need to write your output to file using `FileSystemObject`.

```
' example2.vbs
Main

Sub Main()
    Dim result, fso, fs
    result = 1 / Cos(25)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fs  = fso.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)
    fs.Write result
    fs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah i think I have to write it in a file