# Run a vbs script from another vbs script and redirect right away output to a file

Tags: vbscript, output

Running a vbscript from another vbscript, Is it possible to get right away an output to a file like this one:

```
  dim shell
  set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
  strCMD =replace("'myvbs.vbs' '"&a_parameter&"' ","'","""")
  shell.Run strCMD >output.txt
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Try this example.

```
'script1.vbs -----------------
Dim oShell, strCMD
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCMD = Replace("CMD /C CScript.exe 'script2.vbs' " & 3, "'", """")
oShell.Run strCMD & " //NoLogo >output.txt", 0, True

'script2.vbs -----------------
result = WScript.Arguments(0) ^ 2
WScript.StdOut.Write result
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130070/1856504) too.

Comment: Please could you tell me what does mean '^ 2' in the 'WScript.Arguments(0) ^ 2' expression? Thanks

Comment: @new: `^` is the [exponentiation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze9sfe5f(v=vs.84).aspx). The `WScript.Arguments(0) ^ 2` expression calculates the square of the script's input argument.

Comment: ah ok! I feel ridiculous. I try it for my context and give you feedback. Thanks again

Comment: When doing shell.Run strCMD & " //NoLogo >output.txt", 0, True, so far so good. Nevertheless my file name is into a variable: myFile = "output.txt". Please, How to take account this variable into the shell.Run strCMD & " //NoLogo >output.txt", 0, True expression ?

Comment: I use concatenation and it's good! shell.Run strCMD & " //NoLogo >" & myFile, 0, True. Thanks for your help